# Building a JavaScript build system in Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to work on an application using `node.js`, and am trying to build a JavaScript build system in Sublime Text 3 on my Ubuntu OS. I created a new build system file in Sublime Text called `nodey.sublime-build`, the contents of which were:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node","$file","$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector":"*.js"
}
```

Now, my node.js installation is stored in the following path:  `/tmp/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64`.

However, when I try to run a JavaScript file called `chat.js` which is stored in the following location: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/chat/chat.js`, Sublime Text throws the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'
[cmd: ['node', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/chat/chat.js', 'chat']]
[dir: /opt/lampp/htdocs/chat]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

I'm not really sure if this is the right method for creating a new build system. After building the `nodey` build system, I went to `Tools -> Build System` and selected `nodey`.

What seems to be wrong with my settings?

EDIT:

I ran a `sudo apt-get install node` inside the same directory as `chat.js` , and now when I try to run the JavaScript file in Sublime Text, I get this:

```
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['node', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/chat/chat.js', 'chat']]
[dir: /opt/lampp/htdocs/chat]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

However, even though there are no noticeable errors, the output of the file, which included a `console.log("Hello World")`, wasn't displayed.

Comment: [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) would be a better option

Comment: Doesnt' matter if gulp is better. The command doesn't even seem to run. Is `node` in your $PATH? E.g. can you run `node somefile.js` from your shell?

Comment: @Dodekeract This is what I get after running `node chat.js` from the terminal:  `The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Comment: I have edited my original post slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else encountering the same error, try running the following in your terminal if you're a Linux user:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

This solved the problem in my case.